# to be+infinitive and present progressive usage

Tags: tense, usage, infinitives

Consider the following two sentences:

> Council **is to visit** this place in the next year.

vs

> Council **is visiting** this place in the next year.

Any of them denotes an action, which is planned. What is point of difference between them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both are okay. Both show that the action is planned and likely to happen.

The *be to + infinitive structure* is generally used to discuss formal or official arrangements or to give formal instructions or orders. The [BBC](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv103.shtml) describes it further that --it
is also frequently used in newspaper, radio and television reports to refer to future events. It expresses ***near certainty that what is forecast will happen.***

On the other hand, the present continuous is **also** used when the things are pretty sure to happen.

> The train ***is leaving*** the platform in ten minutes.

Comment: I agree with you but I think that the first grammatical structure conveys a stronger certainty than the second case.+1

Comment: That is, it is more naturally to use in speaking _present progressive_ instead of _to be + infinitive_ for planned action. Am I understand you correctly?

Comment: As I said, both are okay. But here is ***my take*** - I'd prefer using present continuous when the event is quite near!

Comment: As a side note, in our dialect (InE), the *be to + in* structure involves probability. On the other hand, *is..ing* in such context reflects surety.

Comment: You said _I'd prefer using present continuous when the event is quite near!_. But I thought that we must use **to be about + infinitive** construction....

Comment: @DmitryFucintv No. *The train is *about*...* would inject probability again. *The train is leaving...in ...* talks about the event sure to happen.

Answer (score 4):

"S is to V" has several uses:

- it can announce a plan or make an assertion as to the future (as in your example)
- it can give an instruction (as Maulik specified) (this is also compatible with your example--it depends on who is talking to whom)
- it can specify a general guideline or open-ended duty

> Students are to wash their hands after they have come in from outside.
>   
>   The second construction can only play the first of these roles.

It's actually the first construction that expresses less certainty than the first.  It is the appropriate one to use when reporting other people's plans/predictions, without making a subjective commitment about whether you believe that plan/prediction is likely to come true.

It is for this reason that a journalist is more likely to say "The government is to start building the subway next year" than "The government will start building the subway next year" if there is any doubt about whether the building will occur.